# Are the AssertionConsumerService in metadata and saml2 issuer same in SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on

Are the AssertionConsumerService in metadata and saml2 issuer same  in SSO? I am trying to authenticate using SSO but getting error and 400 status.

Answer (score 0):

In general: The *AssertionConsumerService* endpoint is the one used by the IdP to send the SAML Response to. The *issuer* of the assertion will be the entity ID of the IdP.

A SAML compliant ServiceProvider has to perform some checks when consuming the SAML Response, please see SAMLv2 core specification.

The logs of the product/framework you are using should tell you which of the validation checks fail.